# \emph or \textit

Tags: fonts, best-practices, italic, emphasis, semantics

In the comments section of [Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it), I asked for a clarification of these points. The clarification has mostly been made, but it was requested that I turn this into a question to provide for more room for this question to be fielded.

So here it is:

**Please explain the difference between `\emph` and `\textit`. When should they be used, respectively?**

Comment: Nice explanation of the question and other DO's and DON'Ts [DO’s and DON’Ts when typesetting a document](http://chenfuture.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/dos-and-donts-when-typesetting-a-document/)

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Those are very different commands even if the output happens to look the same.

- If you want to emphasize a word or some text, use `\emph`. Don't just make the text italic or bold. If needed, you may change the behaviour of `\emph` whenever you wish in the preamble and the whole document will be adjusted accordingly.
- If you want to get italic text, use `\textit`. `\emph` might have a different effect, a package like `ulem` might change it to underlining for instance.
- `\emph` may be nested: emphasized text within emphasized text may be upright. In contrary, nesting `\textit` just keeps the italic shape.
- Further, I rarely use physical font commands in my body text. I use them to define styles in the preamble and use the styles in the document afterwards, ensuring consistency and allowing changes to be easily made.

Comment: I once got caught by 'ulem's redefinition.  It took me ages to figure out why lots of things were getting underlined all of a sudden.

Comment: The solution to the problem Adrew pointed out is to load ulem with `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`.

Comment: Are there alternative forms of emphasis, one you can call for putting in italics, and one for boldface? (as opposed to explicitly using `\textit{}` and `\textbf{}` all the time)

Comment: stumbled over here because suddenly every \emph element was underlined!

Comment: Is this analogous to the differences between `<em>` and `<i>` tags in HTML? [For example...](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/)

Comment: @bobobobo Actually using `\emph` inside of italic text removes the italics on the emphasized text.

Comment: So let's say I want to mention *Pride and Prejudice* by title, and my style guide says I should italicize it. What do I do in LaTeX? `\emph` or `\textit`?

Comment: @Superbest As above, "If you want to get italic text, use `\textit`". If other italic text would contain the title, it won't be emphasized then. But that's the guide's decision, so be it.

Comment: I've seen the use of `\textit` cause the first line of a block of text to be indented slightly (in comparison to its position before said `\textit` switch was invoked), whereas the use of `\emph` did not have this effect.

Answer (score 88):

The `\emph` macro is designed to be semantic markup. So while by convention it makes text italic, this is not always the case. For example, the `beamer` class makes `\emph` text red as this works better in presentations than using italic.

On the other hand, `\textit` makes text italic, with no variation. Thus it is intended for making text italic when that is exactly what you want.

I would usually favour using `\textit` in a design context, where you are deciding 'these things should be italic'. Normally, that would be in the preamble or a class file, perhaps something like:

```
\newcommand*\latin[1]{\textit{#1}}
```

In the document body, I'd favour the semantic approach and use `\emph`, as this can then be defined in the preamble to do something else entirely.

Comment: Actually, `beamer` leaves `\emph` unchanged, but provides an `\alert` command for red text.