# Tikzpicture graph position

Tags: tikz-graphs

I've got problem with positioning of a graph.
The graph is shown on page 3 instead of page 2 (where it clearly should fit).
I've tried to change the scale to 1.2 (from 1.3). But at when it's less than 1.25, the graph is getting positioned in the middle of a text (Not behind or in front of).
Here is the code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Examination, Grunder i LaTeX, MA1426}
\author{Kristoffer Westring}
\rhead{Kristoffer Westring}
\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 15pt

\rhead{Kristoffer Westring}

\begin{document}
\rhead{Kristoffer Westring }
\maketitle

\pagebreak
En funktion är i matematikens värld en typ av regel som tar ett värde som stoppas in i regeln. Ofta ändras invärdets utvärde. \\
Antag att vi har funktionen \\
$f(x)=3x+2$\\
$f$
är funktionens namn. Den kan heta vad som helst, men ett vanligt namn på funktioner är 
$f$.
Det värde som står innanför paranteserna, i detta fall $x$, kallas för \textit{invärdet}. Invärdet (även kallat \textit{argument}) är det värde som ska genomgå funktionen och komma ut som \textit{utvärde}. Utvärdet är i vårt fall är $f(x)$. \\
Om vi då ser vilket värde $f(x)$ har när $x=2$. Då skriver man $f(2)$ och byter ut de $x$ i funktionen mot $2$. \\
$x=2$ ger oss då att\\
$f(2)=3*2+2=8$\\
Detta kallas för en kontinuerlig funktion. Den har varken slut eller början och linjen är hela tiden kontinuerlig, den bryts aldrig.
\\
\indent
För att tillverka en funktion som kan brytas, kan man ange villkor till en funktion. Vi börjar med att göra två funktioner, $f(x)$ och $g(x)$.\\
Antag att $f(x)=x-3$.\\
Antag att $g(x)=x+3$.\\
Vi har nu två funktioner som kommer att ge oss två parallella linjer. Nu ska vi göra en funktion som har en brytning när $x=0$. Vi använder oss av ytterligare av en funktion $h(x)$.\\
Antag att
$h(x)=f(x), \text{då } x<0$.\\
Antag att 
$h(x)=g(x), \text{då } x\geq 0$\\
\indent
I dessa funktioner har vi villkor. Villkoren är det som efter 'då'.\\ $h(x)$ är alltså lika med $f(x)$ endast när $x$ har värdet $0$ eller högre.\\
För att göra det tydligare brukar man ofta skriva funktioner med villkor på det här sättet.
\\
\[
    h(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    f(x),& \text{då } x\geq 0\\
    g(x),              & \text{då } x<0
\end{cases}
\]
För att vara ännu tydligare kan man även skriva funktionen $h(x)$ genom att skriva ut funktionerna $f(x)$ och $g(x)$. Då ser det istället ut så här.\\
\[
    h(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    x-3,& \text{då } x\geq 0\\
    x+3,              & \text{då } x<0
\end{cases}
\]
\pagebreak
Grafer är ett annat sätt att visa vilket värde $h(x)$ får när $x$ antar ett visst värde. En fördel med att visa hur det ser ut grafiskt är att man får en bra översikt över vilka värden $h(x)$ får. 
\\
\indent
En nackdel är att det är på många $x$ är svårt att se vilket värde $h(x)$ antar.\\
\indent
Om du tittar på \textit{graf 1} så ser du att när $x$ är heltal, är det lätt att se vilket värde $h(x)$ får. Vill du däremot veta vilket värde $h(x)$ får, när $x$ inte är ett heltal är det inte alltid enkelt att se det, genom att bara titta på en graf. 

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.125, >=latex]
\draw[very thin, color=black, dotted, step=1 cm] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\draw[->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {\scriptsize $x$};
\draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,5.5) node[above] {\scriptsize $h(x)$};
\foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,5} \draw (\x, 1pt) -- (\x,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny \x};
\foreach \y in {-5,-4,...,5} \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) node[anchor=east] {\tiny \y};
\draw[color=red, very thick, domain=-1.9:0.0, samples=100]   plot (\x,{(\x)-3})
  node[right] {\large $f(x)$};

\draw[color=green, thick, domain=0.0:2.2, samples=100]   plot (\x,{(\x)+3})
    node[right] {\large $g(x)$};



\foreach \Point in {(0,3)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};
}

\foreach \Point in {(0,-3)}{
    \node at \Point {$\circ$};
}
\node [green] at (0,3) {\textbullet};
\node [red] at (0,-3) {$\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Graf som visar funktionen $h(x)$.}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Some remarks: Do not use a pagebreak to separate the title from the text, use the global option `titlepage` instead. Another documentclass (e.g. report/scrreprt) might be even better. Do *not* use `\\ ` outside of tabular material, as long as you do not know why. Use `\par` or a blank line in your code to make a regular (indented) paragraph. Please have a look at [\emph or \textit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1980) to learn something about `\emph`.

Comment: You can control the positioning of floats [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the positioning specifier.

Edit: Added the centering of the figure and the smaller skip between figure and caption.
You should read some basic Latex Introductions.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp] %you forgot the specifier for the positioning
\addtolength\abovecaptionskip{-15pt} %control the skip between figure and caption
\centering %should be centered
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.125, >=latex]
\draw[very thin, color=black, dotted, step=1 cm] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\draw[->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {\scriptsize $x$};
\draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,5.5) node[above] {\scriptsize $h(x)$};
\foreach \x in {-5,-4,...,5} \draw (\x, 1pt) -- (\x,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny \x};
\foreach \y in {-5,-4,...,5} \draw (1pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y) node[anchor=east] {\tiny \y};
\draw[color=red, very thick, domain=-1.9:0.0, samples=100]   plot (\x,{(\x)-3})
  node[right] {\large $f(x)$};

\draw[color=green, thick, domain=0.0:2.2, samples=100]   plot (\x,{(\x)+3})
    node[right] {\large $g(x)$};



\foreach \Point in {(0,3)}{
    \node at \Point {\textbullet};
}

\foreach \Point in {(0,-3)}{
    \node at \Point {$\circ$};
}
\node [green] at (0,3) {\textbullet};
\node [red] at (0,-3) {$\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Graf som visar funktionen $h(x)$.}
\label{fig:label}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I'd also like to make the graph centered and the caption aligned under the graph. I've tried putting \begin{center} and \end{center} around the whole figure. Didn't work

Comment: What do you mean with aligned under the graph? Less space between caption and graph?

Comment: @user42967 The picture and the caption are both centered in your original example.

Comment: @Johannes_B no it isn't

Comment: @JohannesO Oh right, sorry.