# Proper semantics for italicized foreign words and phrases

Tags: typography, best-practices, italic, semantics

In English, foreign words and phrases such as *per se* and *ibid.* should be italicized, as shown here. There might be a number of ways to accomplish this in LaTeX:

- with `\emph{per se}`
- with `\textit{per se}`
- with `\newcommand\foreign[1]{\textit{#1}}1`

Of these, the first option seems semantically incorrect, the second seems un-LaTeXy, and the third seems a bit verbose (though probably the most correct). Which is the most common practice in LaTeX documents?

Comment: I would go with the third option, but I would change `\textit` to `\emph` so that within nested `\emph`s the emphasis continues to show up.

Comment: I don't think I've seen this convention before. Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Raphael the convention for italicizing foreign words? [Chicago Manual](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/NoneoftheAbove.html), [Purdue Owl (MLA)](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/566/01/), [Wiki Style Guide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Text_formatting#Foreign_terms). Run `Ctrl+F "foreign"` on any of those links to find it.

Comment: See also the posting [\emph or \textit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1980/5001).

Comment: No, the Chicago Manual does not recommedn italicizing et al. or ibid., but it does recommend it for other words.

Comment: You might like to follow the semantic tags defined for XML by the Text Encoding Initiative (TEI).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two relevant differences between the first two commands.

- `\textit` puts its argument in italics, whereas `\emph` can be told which form of typographic emphasis to use: italics (the default), slanted roman (cf. the TeXbook!), bold, bold italics, underline (shudder), small caps, etc.
- `\emph` can handle cases of "nested emphasis". For instance, the "words" `jkl mno` in

  ```
  \emph{abc def ghi \emph{jkl mno} pqr stu}
  ```

  will be set in the upright font to differentiate them from their immediate, italicized surroundings.

I wouldn't say that `\emph` is either more or less "LaTeXy" than `\textit`. Which one to use depends importantly on what you need to achieve. If the command's argument *must* be typeset in italics, then `\textit` is definitely the way to go. This is true, in particular, if there's a chance that the `\emph` macro has been modified -- perhaps by some LaTeX package that you've loaded -- to render its argument in, say, small caps.

Clearly, though, `\foreign{...}` is the *most LaTeXy* method, as it provides an additional layer of abstraction between the text and the way it ends up being typeset.

If you provide the definition

```
\newcommand\foreign[1]{\emph{#1}}
```

you can even handle cases of nested foreign words -- a couple of German words in a passage consisting of French words in a document that's mainly in English?! -- without special effort. And, should you change your mind in the future regarding how "foreign words" ought to be typeset, you needn't mess with the definitions of the lower-level macros `\textit` and `\emph`: You can simply redefine the macro `\foreign` to suit your changed typographic needs.

Comment: @WChargin And by following Mico’s recommendation to define a command \foreign, you can even put in babel’s \foreignlanguage{<language>} to have correct hyphenation.