# How to define a bold font style for \emph text

Tags: fonts, best-practices, emphasis

Recently, I wanted to set all my `\emph`asized text to **bold**, because I think the default *Italic* of `\emph` is not distinctly emphasized.

But I haven't found a solution for it. Please give me some idea. Thanks.

I read a comment on '[\emph or \textit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/emph-or-textit/1983)', it says:

> I rarely use physical font commands in my body text. I use them to define styles in the preamble and use the styles in the document afterwards, ensuring consistency and allowing changes to be easily made.

But I didn't find how to define our own styles, after searching in [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX).

I have tried:

- `\let\emph\textbf`
- `\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{#1}}`

But failed to set **bold** to `\emph` text.

I finally figured out a solution that using **Bold** font for `ItalicFont`:

```
% compile by `xelatex file.tex`
\documentclass{book}
% CJK
\usepackage{xltxtra, xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=Adobe Heiti Std,ItalicFont=Adobe Heiti Std]{Adobe Song Std}
% Latin
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gentium Book Basic}[ItalicFont=Gentium Book Basic Bold]
\begin{document}
I want to bold \emph{emphasized} text.

% bold CJK emphasized text
我想用粗体显示 \emph{强调的} 文字
\end{document}
```

However, I don't think it's a wise solution.

So, any idea? Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. From a first glance your approach should have worked. You are talking about fontspec so i think you are using either `xelatex` or `lualatex`. Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show us the basics of your font selection scheme?