# When to use $something$ syntax?

Tags: formatting

I know the difference between `\emph{something}` and `\textit{something}` ([\emph or \textit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/emph-or-textit)). But when to use syntax like: `$something$`.

Comment: Never. What goes between dollars is *math*, not text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's worth stating simply: anything between dollar signs is math, but it appears in line with the surrounding text (not on a separate line). So you should use `$...$` when you are writing inline math, and you should not use it when you are not writing inline math.

Answer (score 13):

As already commented by Manuel, `$...$` puts the stuff between them into math mode. Here, totally different rules apply, e.g.

- unless it is part of a command (introduced by a backslash) every alphabetical character is considered to be the name of a mathematical variable, i.e. a chain of characters is just a bunch of variables;
- as the characters are treated separately, there's no [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) between them (cf. the "Te" in my example below;
- spaces are ignored;
- there is no hyphenation.

The fact, that the text is printed in italics is just due to [typesetting convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_conventions_in_mathematical_formulae). Hence it is by no means comparable to `\emph{...}` or `\textit{...}` but has a totally different use case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The difference between \verb|\emph{...}| and \verb|$...$|? Just compare it yourself:

\verb|\emph{some Text}|: \emph{some Text}

\verb|$some Text$|: $some Text$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The fact that `\emph` produces italics is also just due to typesetting conventions. Hence it is by no means comparable to `textit`. Although it does not have a totally different use case in the sense that it is not necessarily inappropriate to substitute one for the other. But it has a different use case when considered as semantic markup. (`\emph` can to configured to produce something other than italics e.g. bold or oblique or whatever.)

Comment: You may also want to mention that there's *no ligaturing* going on in math mode. Thus, `\textit{office}` looks very different from `$office$`, and `\textit{fluffy}` and `$fluffy$` also produce rather different results.

Comment: @cfr - As you no doubt know, one of the very nice features of `\emph` is that it can be nested in useful ways; the material in an inner `\emph` environment is usually (but not necessarily) typeset using upright latin letters if the outer `\emph` environment renders its material in italics. In contrast, nesting `\textit` instructions produces no benefit. And, trying to nest `$` symbols is likely to create an error...

Comment: @Mico Yes, I wasn't thinking about that, but that is, of course, a better example.

Comment: @cfr I'm of course aware of the fact that `\emph` is not equal to `\textit` but as the OP already linked a question where the difference is explained and says himself that he understands the difference. Hence I didn't for that part of the story.