# Text definitions - \textit or \emph?

Tags: emphasis

If I want mark definition in text, should I use `\textit` or `\emph`. For example: A `\textit{graph}` is ...

I know, it is not the same.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) how is this related to latex3? (3) I'd use `\emph` because then the emphasize also works in an italic context, `\textit` in an italic context is jut italic, thus you cannot see it.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1980/134144

Comment: `\textit` is *physically* formatting ("make it italic") and `\emph` is a *logical* formatting ("put emphasis on this text"). Now `\emph` uses `\textit` inside normal text, but this could be changed by a class or style. Also `\emph` inside `\emph` works will: the second one makes the text normal again to highlight it in the outer text. So, if you really want something italic use the first one, if you want to highlight something use `\emph`.

Comment: I'm closing our question now, because it was already beeing asked. Please see the above linked question thread which will answer your question.

Comment: @ZYX What you want is to mark something? Well, *define* a macro, and you will have clearer code and you can worry later if you want to change hte definition `\newcommand*\markdefinition[1]{\emph{#1}}` (finding a good name for the command is an art, you might like `\dfntn{..}` more than `\markdefinition{..}` or whatever.

Comment: I see that it is the private issue.

Comment: I write an article and there are definitions. All editors want to mark definitions. So I asked.

Comment: Martin Scharrer do not inflate so much :) It is not the same question. He does not know differences.