# Why I cant see italic font at the header?

Tags: header-footer, lyx, hebrew

I try to put italic text at the header - at the body of the document it's works fine, but at the header I can't see the italic font.
Here is MWE:

```
    % Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.2-2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\labelenumi\arabic{enumii}.}
\lhead{aa\emph{aa}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{english}[variant=american]%
aa\emph{aa}
\end{english}%

\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image]

Do you know how can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: The header and text fonts are different.  The text font appears to be Computer Modern; I'm not sure about the font in the header, but since it's different, it may also go by different rules for handling `\emph`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, *David CLM* does not seem to contain Latin glyphs with an Italic shape. As an additional oddity *Miriam Mono CLM* slants in the opposite way to the other two fonts.

In your question, you have set the default language to Hebrew and the default font to *David CLM*. So this is what you get in your header. If you want English in your header and the default English font of Latin Modern Roman, you could use: `\lhead{\textenglish{aa\emph{aa}}}`, but then you won't get Hebrew if you want it of course.

Also, note that `scrartcl` gives a warning not to use `fancyhdr` with this class. KOMA-Script has its own way of customising headers and footers.

Have a look at this test to see what is going on:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{David CLM}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt{Miriam Mono CLM}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf{Simple CLM}[Script=Hebrew]
\begin{document}
\LR{David CLM}
\medskip

עברית \LR{Latin (Upright)}

{\itshape עברית \LR{Latin (Italic)}}

{\bfseries עברית \LR{Latin (Bold)}}

{\bfseries\itshape עברית \LR{Latin (Bold Italic)}}

\bigskip
\sffamily
\LR{Simple CLM}
\medskip

עברית \LR{Latin (Upright)}

{\itshape עברית \LR{Latin (Italic)}}

{\bfseries עברית \LR{Latin (Bold)}}

{\bfseries\itshape עברית \LR{Latin (Bold Italic)}}

\bigskip
\ttfamily
\LR{Miriam Mono CLM}
\medskip

עברית \LR{Latin (Upright)}

{\itshape עברית \LR{Latin (Italic)}}

{\bfseries עברית \LR{Latin (Bold)}}

{\bfseries\itshape עברית \LR{Latin (Bold Italic)}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: It's working, thank you!! But I don't understand why at the text I get it italic and at the header not, because it should be the same font, right? what the `\textenglish` doing?

Comment: @heblyx It's different because the language and therefore font is different. You have `\begin{english}` and `\end{english}` around the text that works in your main document. This changes the font away from *David CLM*. You don't have this in your header. `\textenglish{}` does the same as `\begin...\end{english}` but for short text within a paragraph. Is your document mainly in English or Hebrew?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`\lhead{\textit{aa\emph{aa}}}`

`\textit` is to command to put text in italic.

Comment: why would you make a text italic which is already emphasised? May be could you add a complete solution if possible?

Comment: Emphasis depends of how the text is. It will now be in bold.

Comment: I am not sure about that. Please check https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/emph-or-textit

Comment: Did you actually check this? I do not think it works.

Comment: Not working.... :(

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled using your source code. The solution is:
you can change the family font using in header.

**a)** try this line:

```
\lhead{\textrm{ aa\emph{aa}}}
```

the \textrm is to set serif (roman).

**b)** you can use \textsf to set sans serif family, try this line:

```
\lhead{\textrm{ aa\emph{aa}}}
```

**c)** you can use \texttt to set typewriter (monospace) family, try this line:

```
\lhead{\texttt{ aa\emph{aa}}}
```

Comment: Are you sure `\textrm` works? It does not work for me and I wouldn't expect different output since this is the default font family in use. The other two do work, but this changes the font which the OP might not want.