# Problem Bibdesk syntax

Tags: syntax, bibdesk

I'm writing a document with a bibliography using Bibdesk. Some of my booktitles include other titles which implies to adapt the style to prevent any confusion but I don't know how to do that.

For instance, I get: *An introduction to Plato's Philebus* but I want: *An introduction to Plato's* Philebus.

The entry in bibdesk is : Plato's \textit{{Philebus}}. I tried : An Introduction to Plato's \textrm{{Philebus}} but it doesn't work either.

I do not have this problem with articles. The command \textit{{...}} works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly question from me. I used \emph{} and it works perfecly fine.

Comment: `\emph{}` is a logical formatting macro (i.e. *emphase* it in its surrounding text), while `\textit` etc. is a physical one (i.e. use this specific font no matter what). While both will give you the same optical result in a normal text, `\emph` is programmed in a context-sensitive way, i.e. it nests! `A sentence with \emph{some highlighted text with \emph{something important} in it}, ...` will give you the encapsulated `\emph` as roman font again. This behaviour is configurable for different output drivers. See [emph or textit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/emph-or-textit).